# How do you loop through a dataframe and convert rows to JSON objects

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I am creating a function that sends data to a remote server. I am currently using the pandas library to read through a CSV file and convert the data to a dataframe. What I need to do is loop through that dataframe and covert each row to JSON and send them to my database.

The reason I need to loop through is that sets of data that are too big (currently sending 100 row by 21 col) are too long for HTML strings. What I need to do is send loop through and send lots of 10 or so.

Below is where I am at the moment:

```
def UploadData(root, self, data):
        i = 0
        data_arr = []
        for row in data:
            if i % 5 == 0:
                # Add row to array or something
                data_arr.append(row)
                json_str = data_arr.to_json(orient='records')
                url = 'https://newsimland.com/~db/JSON/?tok={"tok":"YOUR TOKEN HERE","cmd":{"STORE":"test_database","VALUE":'+ json_str +'}}'
                r = requests.get(url)
            else:
                # Add row to array
                data_arr.append(row)
            i += 1
        data = r.json()
        if r.status_code == 200:
            Alert(title="Error", text="Data upload unsuccessful")
        else:
            Alert(title="Success", text="Data upload successful")
```

One of the problems with this is that `.to_json(orient='records')` is meant for a dataframe, not the array I am appending to. Also if the original dataframe is less than 5 rows, it wont send the data to the database.

Does anyone know how I could achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to send your DataFrame in parts of 5 or fewer rows. In this case I recommend you to split the dataframe in the following way, so that the rows are retained as a DataFrame and you can use `to_json`.

```
import numpy as np

def UploadData(root, self, data):
    size = 5
    for chunk in np.split(data, np.arange(size, data.size, size)):
        if chunk.size:
            json_str = chunk.to_json(orient='records')
            # Send your data here!
```